# list filter expression. short version

Tags: c#, list, lambda

I have a list of objects, to simplify things, lets just say each object has 2 fields ID and Date.

There CAN be 2 or more items with same ID and different date.
I want to filter them and return a list with the ID field being unique and the LATEST date they had.

For example

Input:

## ID, DATE

(1, 6/12/14)

(1, 5/16/14)

(1, 5/13/14)

(2, 5/10/14)

(2, 5/12/14)

Output:

## ID, DATE

(1, 6/12/14)

(2, 5/12/14)

I expect something like:

> myList.Where(SOMETHING).toList();

But cant find the way to do it :(

## EDIT:

Tried:

> caseT.Surveys.GroupBy(item => item.ID).Select(grouping => new Survey()
>   { ID = grouping.Key, TimeOfSurveyOpen = grouping.Max(item =>
>   item.TimeOfSurveyOpen)}).ToList();

It returns the same, like there is no filtering.

Comment: Are you sure your IDs are exactly the same?  The GroupBy will limit the list to returning 1 entry per ID.  Can you show us the code around the query, so we can see how you're using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend grouping by ID, then mapping each grouping to {Id, Max(date)}

Pseudocode because I don't have an IDE up:

```
myList
   .GroupBy(item => item.Id)
   .Select(grouping => new Item(grouping.Key, grouping.Max(item => item.Date)))
```

Comment: new `Item`, where `Item` is an item of my list does not work.

Comment: Not working, I'm getting the same items all the time